# angular drag and drop cdk doesn't work in angular material dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, angulardraganddroplists

I want to change list order by drag and drop CDK of angular.
It works on any page in my website, but when I use it inside a material dialog it doesn't work.
When I drag a list item over another item, it doesn't change position on dragging over, also not on drop.
Is there anything special to do to make it work inside the dialog?

simplest code that I am trying:

HTML

```html
<div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div cdkDrag *ngFor="let n of numbers">
    {{n}}
  </div>
</div>
```

ts file

```
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

numbers: number[]= [];

constructor() {
  this.n.push(2,3,4,5);
}

drop(event: CdkDragDrop<number[]>) {
  moveItemInArray(this.numbers, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@NgModule({ imports: [..., DragDropModule]})
```

As I said, this code works in any place in any page, but when i copy it to dialog component it does not work

Comment: did you find any solution ? I am in the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Found a temporary solution (by @DeonduPreez) here:

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/15880#issuecomment-523476619

The idea is to keep the current scroll position before the dialog opens, 
then scroll to the top,
then open the dialog,
and lastly, after the dialog closes, scroll back to the saved location.

```
const doc = document.documentElement;
const left = (window.pageXOffset || doc.scrollLeft) - (doc.clientLeft || 0);
const top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop) - (doc.clientTop || 0);

if (top != 0 || left != 0) {
  window.scrollTo({ top : 0, left: 0 });
}
const modal: MatDialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalComponent);
modal.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
if (top != 0 || left != 0) {
    window.scroll({ top : top, left : left, behavior: "smooth" });
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you RoiTr! This is working for me. Is there a solution from Material team? Because end user notices the page moves up and down in the background.

Comment: @SushrutParanjape Unfortunately it seems like it's still a bug. Look at the discussion here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14280 - People say they use  .cdk-global-scrollblock { top: 0 !important; } in their global styling and it fixes it.